# Grails - trying to deploy a nojars application into glassfish 3.0.1

Tags: grails, groovy, glassfish

Because of memory constraint i am trying to build a grails app with smaller memory footprint. I build the war with this argument "--nojars". I created a war file without all the jar and when i deploy within the glassfish i encounter this error

Exception while loading the app : java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.Log4jConfigListener

It seems like the application fail to find where is the jar file.

I had already indicates the path to the library before deploying the application in glassfish.

did i miss out somethinng?

Answer (score 0):

It is commonly recommended to use GlassFish's [Common Classloader](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3672/beadj?a=view). That means putting the shared JARS into the *$domain-dir/lib* folder (but *not* into a subfolder of that).

You're probably trying to use the *Application Classloader* with the `asadmin deploy --libraries` command. This is more complicated and error-prone. If you don't need different versions of the same JARs with different web applications, you should definitely go for the *Common Classloader* as specified above.

Also see [The Classloader Hierarchy](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3672/beadf?a=view) for a reference.

---

**EDIT** Updated as per the questioner's comment:

The `domain/domain1/lib` folder definitely works (I've tested that). To validate that, put `log4j.jar` into that folder and add a `test.jsp` to `domain1/applications/$applicationName`, that just contains:

```
<% out.println(
    org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(this.getClass())); %>
```

---

If that works but your other code does not, there may be another point to consider: Are you using Log4J's `Logger.getLogger(..)` or Apache Commons' `LogFactory.getInstance(..)` in your code?

See the article [Taxonomy of class loader problems encountered when using Jakarta Commons Logging](http://articles.qos.ch/classloader.html) for related issues. - I'd also like to advise you to post your complete stacktrace.

Comment: i tried putting all the jar into domain/domain1/lib or domain/domain1/lib/applibs or domain/domain1/lib/ext and all the class file into domain/domain1/lib/classes along with all the folder into here as well but it still give me the same error

Comment: Note that my answer has been extended.