# How to generate grails jar components for glassfish

Tags: grails, glassfish

Found in this [tuto](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4496/6nfv5l577/index.html) the cmd to deploy a grails app on Glassfish application server:

```
asadmin deploy --libraries $GRAILS_HOME/lib/glassfish-grails.jar helloworld-0.1.war
```

Browsing to `$GRAILS_HOME/lib/` , don't find `glassfish-grails.jar` file .

From where can someone get this library ? i mean :glassfish-grails.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That stuff is badly dated and I don't think they've updated it in 4 years. For some reason it didn't even appear to be open source when I look at this a year or so ago.

There was plugin but it's almost as dated. The repo has seen some updates fairly recently, so if you wanted to get this thing to the finish line it seems very doable and I think it'd be a great addition.

I would be willing to help out some after the holidays It looks like just updating the glassfish-embedded-all dependency to `'org.glassfish.main.extras:glassfish-embedded-all:4.1'` and ensuring that the plugin code compiles would be a chunk of the work, with ensuring that it functions being the remaining :) See [http://mvnrepository.com/](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.main.extras/glassfish-embedded-all/4.1) for more info, dependencies, etc.

Feel free to email me if you get stuck or want to know anything about getting a new server to act like Tomcat and Jetty do in run-app - I've worked on both of those.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial was written for the Glassfish v3 Prelude version, a very early version of Glassfish 3, and seems to be invalid for current versions of Glassfish 3.

The file `glassfish-grails.jar` doesn't exist anymore in the GRAILS lib folder, but it isn't needed anyway.

To make a shared-war (a WAR without the lib files) work, you have to do the following:

1. Copy all the libs from `$GRAILS_HOME/lib/` to `$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/lib/`.
2. Deploy it via: `asadmin deploy helloworld-0.1.war` (or use the Glassfish Admin GUI)

Everything else should work as described in the tutorial.

**See also:**

- [Grails - trying to deploy a nojars application into glassfish 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193065/grails-trying-to-deploy-a-nojars-application-into-glassfish-3-0-1)